# Django: One endpoint, POST open to all, GET requires authentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Using Latest Django/Django Rest Framwork.

I can't figure out how to allow one endpoint to have the following rules:

POST - open to anyone (AllowAny permission)
GET - Authenticated.

There is no way to have conditional permissions depending on the method, so there's only one way to change permissions are on a per-view like this:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def users_view(request):
    return Response("Okay!")
```

Of course there is no way to do something like this:

```
# I have authentication turned on by default in my settings.py file 

@api_view(['GET'])
def users_view(request):
    return Response("Okay - you're authenticated")


@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def users_view(request):
    return Response("Okay! this is a public endpoint")
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up doing something like this:

```
class AllowPostOnlyPermission(BasePermission):
    """
    The request is permitted only if the method is POST
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if (request.method == 'POST' or
                request.user and request.user.is_authenticated()):
                return True
        return False
```

And I simply added this:

```
@api_view(['POST', 'GET'])
@permission_classes([AllowPostOnlyPermission])
def users_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return Response("Okay GET")
        pass
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        return Response("Okay POST")
```

Now my non-credentialed requests fail on GET, but succeed on POST.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is ok but for a small tweak in the has_permission method.
You have this

```
def has_permission(self, request, view):
    if (request.method == 'POST' or
            request.user and request.user.is_authenticated**()**):
            return True
    return Falseenter code here
```

I changed it to this

```
def has_permission(self, request, view):
    if (request.method == 'POST' or
            request.user and request.user.is_authenticated):
            return True
    return Falseenter code hereenter code here
```